# Interpreting accelerometer data as accuracy measure

Tags: accelerometer

To test the movement stability of my line following cart. I used the accelerometer of my xperia x8. I will put different loads in my cart. Can you suggest some parameters that i can measure or analyze from the 3 axis accelerometer readings? I will compare the acce reeadings from the different loads. Thank you!

Comment: can give more description, what exactly you are trying